# SNMP OID to detect network equipment vendor

Tags: snmp

Is there a SNMP OID to detect network equipment vendor name? For Cisco and Juniper equipment I have used sysDescr.0(.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0), which among other data includes the vendor name. However, this is usually a multi-line string with no fixed structure and needs to be parsed if used in scripts. Maybe there is a standard OID to query equipment vendor name? Or equipment OS(Junos, IOS XR, IOS, IOS XE, etc) family?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's not a single OID tree to describe the equipment.  There is a vendor-specific tree, and each vendor implements their own MIB tree under that.  Whether or not any particular vendor bothers (major enterprise vendors do) is a matter for them.  Within their own tree the vendor can define whatever they like and that may include the model.  Not all equipment from a single vendor will support their entire MIB tree.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know the OID for network equipment vendor(or operating system) for example for Cisco?

Comment: I think the root is at 1.3.6.1.4.1.9, you can always try walking the MIB (snmpwalk on *NIX) if you have decent bandwidth to the device.

Answer (score 1):

There's the generic [RFC4133 Entity MIB](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4133) which may be useful to get more exact description of the hardware brand and model and its components. If you go through the entPhysicalTable subtree (`1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.2`), you may find some more useful information.

For example:

A Juniper router:

```
.1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.2.1 = STRING: "Juniper MX240 Internet Backbone Router"
```

An Arista 7050-SX switch:

```
.1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.2.1 = STRING: "48 SFP+ + 4 QSFP+ 1RU"
```

A Cisco ASR:

```
.1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.2.1 = STRING: "Cisco ASR1002 Chassis"
```

However, not all vendors implement this MIB, and some provide more detailed information than others.

Answer (score 0):

1.3.6.1.4.1.47 is the root OID for Cisco.

Comment: This is the base OID for Cisco's vendor specific MIB. Although presence of values in this subtree may indicate that the device polled is a Cisco device, there are better ways to determine this.